# KVM guest can't find gateway

Tags: linux, debian, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, bridge

I try to setup a KVM server with bridged networking. I followed the docs, but still can't get it working. The guest system can ping the host system and the host the guest system, so the connection between this two seem to work.

I basically just want that the KVM guest is in the same network like the Host system and that they share the ethernet port.

I'd really appreciate if anyone can give me a tip how to get it working.

/etc/config/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth1 inet manual
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
address 172.16.66.22
network 172.16.66.0
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 172.16.66.254
broadcast 172.16.66.255
bridge_stp off
bridge_ports eth1
bridge_maxwait 0
bridge_fd 0
```

output of ifconfig on the server:

```
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:c0:dd:0b:84:3e  
      inet addr:172.16.66.22  Bcast:172.16.66.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: 2401:f000:3:0:2c0:ddff:fe0b:843e/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: fe80::2c0:ddff:fe0b:843e/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:12363 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:853 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:1939520 (1.8 MiB)  TX bytes:308716 (301.4 KiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:c0:dd:0b:84:3e  
      inet6 addr: fe80::2c0:ddff:fe0b:843e/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:12444 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:915 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:256 
      RX bytes:2133993 (2.0 MiB)  TX bytes:312032 (304.7 KiB)
      Interrupt:18 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:976 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:976 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:323811 (316.2 KiB)  TX bytes:323811 (316.2 KiB)

vnet0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:54:00:9a:a0:14  
      inet6 addr: fe80::fc54:ff:fe9a:a014/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:71 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:11443 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
      RX bytes:3946 (3.8 KiB)  TX bytes:1969514 (1.8 MiB

$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1

$ brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br0     8000.00c0dd0b843e   no      eth1
                                    vnet0

$ ps -ef | egrep '(qemu|kvm)'
root      1346     2  0 13:20 ?        00:00:00 [kvm-irqfd-clean]
105       1823     1  3 13:22 ?        00:04:45 /usr/bin/kvm -S -M pc-0.12 -enable-kvm -m 512 -smp 1,sockets=1,cores=1,threads=1 -name secondserver -uuid 3c31fa7d-6fe7-26fa-e62e-3b948a4023a4 -nodefaults -chardev socket,id=monitor,path=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/secondserver.monitor,server,nowait -mon chardev=monitor,mode=readline -rtc base=utc -boot c -drive file=/dev/kvm-server/secondserver,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk0,boot=on,format=raw,cache=none -device virtio-blk-pci,bus=pci.0,addr=0x4,drive=drive-virtio-disk0,id=virtio-disk0 -drive if=none,media=cdrom,id=drive-ide0-1-0,readonly=on,format=raw -device ide-drive,bus=ide.1,unit=0,drive=drive-ide0-1-0,id=ide0-1-0 -device virtio-net-pci,vlan=0,id=net0,mac=52:54:00:9a:a0:14,bus=pci.0,addr=0x3 -net tap,fd=66,vlan=0,name=hostnet0 -chardev pty,id=serial0 -device isa-serial,chardev=serial0 -usb -device usb-tablet,id=input0 -vnc 127.0.0.1:0 -k en-us -vga cirrus -device virtio-balloon-pci,id=balloon0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x5

$ iptables -L && iptables -L -t nat
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination  

$ brctl showmacs br0
port no mac addr        is local?   ageing timer
1   00:0c:42:30:ef:cb   no         5.94
1   00:0e:08:d7:32:dd   no        41.34
1   00:0e:08:dd:9f:94   no        30.49
1   00:0e:08:dd:9f:96   no        46.45
1   00:19:b9:08:2f:6d   no         0.00
1   00:1a:c1:f3:95:66   no         1.98
1   00:c0:dd:0b:84:3e   yes        0.00
1   3c:ce:73:d2:67:2f   no        53.84
1   3c:ce:73:d2:67:3c   no         6.84
1   44:d3:ca:78:b4:b1   no        13.97
1   98:d6:bb:61:44:43   no       186.44
1   f4:ce:46:48:ef:1f   no         4.46
2   fe:54:00:9a:a0:14   yes        0.00

$ tail -n 3 /etc/sysctl.conf
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 0
```

I also did a tcpdump on the server and when I try from the Client to the gateway then I get the following output:

```
16:12:32.533844 ARP, Request who-has 172.16.66.254 tell 172.16.66.36, length 28
...
```

In the end it fails, because it can't reach the gateway.

I made screenshots of the client network configuration as well, because I had no internet connection yet to install openssh.

http://bit.ly/VN9fnl
http://bit.ly/X07sgo

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be not in host or guest configuration, but on the adjacent network device.

As a first guess I can imagine you have port-security feature enabled on a switch, allowing only 1 device on ethernet connection. But there could be a lot of other things.

Comment: I solved the issue indirectly. I just used a Broadcom NIC now and that was actually working. So it's not a KVM issue but probably a driver/driver configuration issue of the QLogic NIC.